# php array echo out values that contains p1

Tags: php, arrays, echo, contains

hi i have an array of about 20/30 items big.

i need to have it loop threw the array and echo out only the items with the text p1 in them.

the array looks like so

```
    "lolly","lollyp1","top","topp1","bum","bump1","gee","geep1"
```

and so on

i have tried to use something like this

```
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $needle = htmlspecialchars($_GET["usr"]);
    $ret = array_keys(array_filter($arr, function($var) use ($needle){
    return strpos($var, $needle) !== false;
    }));
```

but all this gives me is a blank page or 1s

how can i have it echo out the items with p1 in them ?

Comment: I would use strpos in the loop and match on "p1" as the needle....for example, echo "<ol>"; pre-loop, echo "<li>$value</li>"; on loop iteration  matches, and echo "</ol>"; post-loop

Comment: i get a page full of number 1s or a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$needle = htmlspecialchars($_GET["usr"]);
$rtnArray = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $rtnArray = strpos($value,$needle);
};
return $rtnArray;
```

If your trying to write directly to the page the lose the $rtnarray and echo:

```
$needle = htmlspecialchars($_GET["usr"]);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo strpos($value,$needle);
};
```

To only show ones with 'p1' then filter:

```
$needle = htmlspecialchars($_GET["usr"]);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $temp = strpos($value,$needle);
    if($temp > 1){
        echo $value;
    }
};
```

Comment: your last answear works great if the user enters p1 it shows them all perfectly but i have noticed a problem if the user puts the full item into there usr get request like gleep1 then it dosent echo out glee1 how would i made it do this as well just in case the user dose add the full tem to the get

Comment: If the user puts the entire value you strpos will return 0 because it found it at the beginning of the value.  You can do a catch for this by comparing the value to the needle if they match the  echo that value

Answer (score 0):

Using a direct loop with string-comparison would be a simple way to go here:

```
$needle = $_GET['usr'];
$matches = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value, $needle) !== false) {
        $matches[] = $key;
    }
}
```

The use of `array_filter()` in your post *should* work, pending the version of PHP you're using. Try updating to use a separate / defined function:

```
function find_needle($var) {
    global $needle;
    return strpos($var, $needle) !== false;
}
$ret = array_keys(array_filter($arr, 'find_needle'));
```

[**Codepad Example**](http://codepad.org/rZlm7OeQ) of the second sample